# Alexa is not recognizing my intents

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Alexa isn't recognizing my intents that have slots. Alexa recognizes all of my intents that don't have slots, but not the ones that have slots. For example, Alexa recognizes "view chores", but not "view chore {chore}". This only happens when running on an actual device,not the simulator. Why is this happening?

Interaction Model:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "AddChoreIntent",
      "samples": [
        "add chore",
        "add chore for {person}",
        "add chore {chore} for {person}",
        "add chore {chore}",
        "add chore {chore} at {time}",
        "add chore {chore} for {person} at {time}",
        "add chore for {person} at {time}",
        "add chore at {time}",
        "add chore repeating {interval}",
        "add chore {chore} repeating {interval}",
        "add chore {chore} for {person} repeating {interval}",
        "add chore {chore} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "add chore {chore} for {person} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "add chore at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to add a chore",
        "i want to add a chore for {person}",
        "i want to add a chore {chore} for {person} ",
        "i want to add a chore {chore}",
        "i want to add a chore {chore} at {time}",
        "i want to add a chore {chore} for {person} at {time}",
        "i want to add a chore for {person} at {time}",
        "i want to add a chore at {time} ",
        "i want to add a chore repeating {interval}",
        "i want to add a chore {chore} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to add a chore {chore} for {person} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to add a chore {chore} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to add a chore {chore} for {person} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to add a chore at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to create a chore",
        "i want to create a chore for {person}",
        "i want to create a chore {chore} for {person}",
        "i want to create a chore {chore}",
        "i want to create a chore {chore} at {time}",
        "i want to create a chore {chore} for {person} at {time}",
        "i want to create a chore for {person} at {time}",
        "i want to create a chore at {time} ",
        "i want to create a chore repeating {interval}",
        "i want to create a chore {chore} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to create a chore {chore} for {person} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to create a chore {chore} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to create a chore {chore} for {person} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "i want to create a chore at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "create a chore",
        "create a chore for {person}",
        "create a chore {chore} for {person}",
        "create a chore {chore}",
        "create a chore {chore} at {time}",
        "create a chore {chore} for {person} at {time}",
        "create a chore for {person} at {time}",
        "create a chore at {time} ",
        "create a chore repeating {interval}",
        "create a chore {chore} repeating {interval}",
        "create a chore {chore} for {person} repeating {interval}",
        "create a chore {chore} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "create a chore {chore} for {person} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "create a chore at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "create chore",
        "create chore {chore}",
        "create chore for {person}",
        "create chore {chore} for {person} ",
        "create chore {chore} at {time}",
        "create chore {chore} for {person} at {time}",
        "create chore for {person} at {time}",
        "create chore at {time} ",
        "create chore repeating {interval}",
        "create chore {chore} repeating {interval}",
        "create chore {chore} for {person} repeating {interval}",
        "create chore {chore} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "create chore {chore} for {person} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "create chore at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "add a chore",
        "add a chore for {person}",
        "add a chore {chore} for {person} ",
        "add a chore {chore}",
        "add a chore {chore} at {time}",
        "add a chore {chore} for {person} at {time}",
        "add a chore for {person} at {time}",
        "add a chore at {time} ",
        "add a chore repeating {interval}",
        "add a chore {chore} repeating {interval}",
        "add a chore {chore} for {person} repeating {interval}",
        "add a chore {chore} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "add a chore {chore} for {person} at {time} repeating {interval}",
        "add a chore at {time} repeating {interval}"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "chore",
          "type": "Chore",
          "samples": [
            "{chore}",
            "the chore is {chore}",
            "the chore will be {chore}",
            "the chore {chore}",
            "add chore {chore}",
            "add the chore {chore}",
            "add {chore}"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "person",
          "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME",
          "samples": [
            "{person}",
            "{person} will do this chore",
            "{person} will",
            "it will be {person}"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "time",
          "type": "AMAZON.TIME",
          "samples": [
            "{time}",
            "at {time}",
            "it will be done at {time}",
            "it will be performed at {time}",
            "the time is {time}",
            "the time to do this chore will be {time}",
            "the time will be {time}"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "interval",
          "type": "Interval",
          "samples": [
            "{interval}",
            "it will be performed {interval}",
            "it will be done {interval}",
            "the interval is {interval}"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
      "samples": []
    },
    {
      "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
      "samples": []
    },
    {
      "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
      "samples": []
    },
    {
      "name": "DeleteChoreIntent",
      "samples": [
        "delete chore {chore}",
        "delete the chore {chore}",
        "delete a chore",
        "i want to delete chore {chore}",
        "i want to delete the chore {chore}",
        "i want to delete a chore"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "chore",
          "type": "Chore",
          "samples": [
            "the chore is {chore}",
            "{chore}",
            "delete the chore {chore}",
            "delete {chore}",
            "delete chore {chore}"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "EditChoreIntent",
      "samples": [
        "edit the person of chore {chore} to {person}",
        "edit the person of the chore {chore} to {person}",
        "edit the person of a chore to {person}",
        "i want to edit the person of chore {chore} to {person}",
        "i want to edit the person of the chore {chore} to {person}",
        "i want to edit the person of a chore to {person}",
        "edit the time of chore {chore} to {time}",
        "edit the time of the chore {chore} to {time}",
        "edit the time of a chore to {time}",
        "i want to edit the time of chore {chore} to {time}",
        "i want to edit the time of the chore {chore} to {time}",
        "i want to edit the time of a chore to {time}",
        "edit the interval of chore {chore} to {interval}",
        "edit the interval of the chore {chore} to {interval}",
        "edit the interval of a chore to {interval}",
        "i want to edit the interval of chore {chore} to {interval}",
        "i want to edit the interval of the chore {chore} to {interval}",
        "i want to edit the interval of a chore to {interval}",
        "change the person of chore {chore} to {person}",
        "change the person of the chore {chore} to {person}",
        "change the person of a chore to {person}",
        "i want to change the person of chore {chore} to {person}",
        "i want to change the person of the chore {chore} to {person}",
        "i want to change the person of a chore to {person}",
        "change the time of chore {chore} to {time}",
        "change the time of the chore {chore} to {time}",
        "change the time of a chore to {time}",
        "i want to change the time of chore {chore} to {time}",
        "i want to change the time of the chore {chore} to {time}",
        "i want to change the time of a chore to {time}",
        "change the interval of chore {chore} to {interval}",
        "change the interval of the chore {chore} to {interval}",
        "change the interval of a chore to {interval}",
        "i want to change the interval of chore {chore} to {interval}",
        "i want to change the interval of the chore {chore} to {interval}",
        "i want to change the interval of a chore to {interval}",
        "edit the person of {chore} to {person}",
        "edit the person of the {chore} to {person}",
        "i want to edit the person of {chore} to {person}",
        "i want to edit the person of the {chore} to {person}",
        "edit the time of {chore} to {time}",
        "edit the time of the {chore} to {time}",
        "i want to edit the time of {chore} to {time}",
        "i want to edit the time of the {chore} to {time}",
        "edit the interval of {chore} to {interval}",
        "edit the interval of the {chore} to {interval}",
        "i want to edit the interval of {chore} to {interval}",
        "i want to edit the interval of the {chore} to {interval}",
        "change the person of {chore} to {person}",
        "change the person of the {chore} to {person}",
        "i want to change the person of {chore} to {person}",
        "i want to change the person of the {chore} to {person}",
        "change the time of {chore} to {time}",
        "change the time of the {chore} to {time}",
        "i want to change the time of {chore} to {time}",
        "i want to change the time of the {chore} to {time}",
        "change the interval of {chore} to {interval}",
        "change the interval of the {chore} to {interval}",
        "i want to change the interval of {chore} to {interval}",
        "i want to change the interval of the {chore} to {interval}"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "chore",
          "type": "Chore",
          "samples": [
            "{chore}",
            "the chore {chore}",
            "edit chore {chore}",
            "edit {chore}",
            "edit the chore {chore}"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "person",
          "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "time",
          "type": "AMAZON.TIME",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "interval",
          "type": "Interval",
          "samples": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "RenameChoreIntent",
      "samples": [
        "rename {chore} to {newChore}",
        "rename the chore {chore}",
        "rename {chore}",
        "rename the chore {chore} to {newChore}",
        "i want to rename {chore} to {newChore}",
        "i want to rename the chore {chore}",
        "i want to rename {chore}",
        "i want to rename the chore {chore} to {newChore}"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "chore",
          "type": "Chore",
          "samples": [
            "{chore}",
            "the chore is {chore}",
            "the chore will be {chore}",
            "the chore {chore}",
            "rename {chore}",
            "rename the chore {chore}"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "newChore",
          "type": "Chore",
          "samples": [
            "{newChore}",
            "the chore is {newChore}",
            "the chore will be {newChore}",
            "the chore {newChore}",
            "rename {chore} to {newChore}",
            "rename the chore to {newChore}",
            "rename the chore {chore} to {newChore}"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ViewChoreDetailsIntent",
      "samples": [
        "i want to view the chore {chore}",
        "i want to see the chore {chore}",
        "i want to see chore {chore}",
        "i want to view chore {chore}",
        "view chore {chore}",
        "view a chore",
        "i want to view a chore",
        "view chore",
        "chore {chore}"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "chore",
          "type": "Chore",
          "samples": [
            "{chore}",
            "view the chore {chore}",
            "the chore {chore}",
            "view chore {chore}",
            "view {chore}"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ViewChoresIntent",
      "samples": [
        "view chores",
        "view chores for {person}",
        "view the chores for {person}",
        "view {person} chores",
        "view my chores",
        "view all chores",
        "view the chores",
        "view all of {person} chores",
        "view all the chores",
        "i want to view chores",
        "i want to view chores for {person}",
        "i want to view the chores for {person}",
        "i want to view {person} chores",
        "i want to view my chores",
        "i want to view all chores",
        "i want to view the chores",
        "i want to view all of {person} chores",
        "i want to view all the chores",
        "i want to see chores",
        "i want to see chores for {person}",
        "i want to see the chores for {person}",
        "i want to see {person} chores",
        "i want to see all chores",
        "i want to see the chores",
        "i want to see all of {person} chores",
        "i want to see all the chores",
        "my chores",
        "the chores",
        "what are my chores",
        "what are the chores",
        "{person} chores",
        "what are {person} chores"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "person",
          "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME",
          "samples": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "types": [
    {
      "name": "Chore",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "washing dishes",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "walking the dog",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "making the bed",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "doing laundry",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "cleaning the table",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "drying dishes",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "mopping the floor",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "making dinner",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "organizing the bedroom",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "mopping",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "cleaning",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "washing",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "taking out the trash",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "washing clothes",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "watering plants",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "cleaning the pool",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "watering the plant",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "watering the plants",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Interval",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "daily",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "monthly",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": {
            "value": "weekly",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "prompts": [
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-AddChoreIntent.IntentSlot-chore",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "Which chore?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore should I add?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore do you want to add?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-AddChoreIntent.IntentSlot-person",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "Who will perform this chore?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "Who will do this chore?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-AddChoreIntent.IntentSlot-time",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "At what time should this chore be performed?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "When should this chore be performed?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-AddChoreIntent.IntentSlot-interval",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "At what interval should this chore be performed?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Confirm.Intent-DeleteChoreIntent",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "Are you sure you want to delete the chore {chore}?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-DeleteChoreIntent.IntentSlot-chore",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore should I delete?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore do you want to delete?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "Which chore?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-EditChoreIntent.IntentSlot-chore",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore do you want to edit?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-RenameChoreIntent.IntentSlot-chore",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore do you want to rename?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-RenameChoreIntent.IntentSlot-newChore",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What do you want to rename the chore to?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-ViewChoreDetailsIntent.IntentSlot-chore",
      "promptVersion": "1.0",
      "definitionVersion": "1.0",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore do you want to view?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "What chore?"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "dialog": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "intents": [
      {
        "name": "AddChoreIntent",
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {},
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "chore",
            "type": "Chore",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-AddChoreIntent.IntentSlot-chore"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "person",
            "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-AddChoreIntent.IntentSlot-person"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "time",
            "type": "AMAZON.TIME",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-AddChoreIntent.IntentSlot-time"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "interval",
            "type": "Interval",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-AddChoreIntent.IntentSlot-interval"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "DeleteChoreIntent",
        "confirmationRequired": true,
        "prompts": {
          "confirm": "Confirm.Intent-DeleteChoreIntent"
        },
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "chore",
            "type": "Chore",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-DeleteChoreIntent.IntentSlot-chore"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "EditChoreIntent",
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {},
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "chore",
            "type": "Chore",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-EditChoreIntent.IntentSlot-chore"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "person",
            "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME",
            "elicitationRequired": false,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {}
          },
          {
            "name": "time",
            "type": "AMAZON.TIME",
            "elicitationRequired": false,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {}
          },
          {
            "name": "interval",
            "type": "Interval",
            "elicitationRequired": false,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "RenameChoreIntent",
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {},
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "chore",
            "type": "Chore",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-RenameChoreIntent.IntentSlot-chore"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "newChore",
            "type": "Chore",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-RenameChoreIntent.IntentSlot-newChore"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ViewChoreDetailsIntent",
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {},
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "chore",
            "type": "Chore",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-ViewChoreDetailsIntent.IntentSlot-chore"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the Alexa app to see the transcription of what Alexa is actually hearing; then test those transcriptions in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have added all possible slots in Custom Slot Types (If you are note using Amazon default slots) in all enabled languages. If your's is custom slot and that slot is not added in Custom Slot Types then alexa cannot accurately catch it